# change the structure content of a div (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript

Sorry if you found this question dumb, but maybe is because is the evening, i don't find the solution.

Basicly, i create a div with some stuff in js. for exemple

```
function a(){
    var div = createElement('div');
    var div2 = createElement('div');
    // I add stuff to div 2
    var div3 = createElement('div');
    // I add stuff to div 3

    div.appendChild(div2);
    div.appendChild(div3);

    return div;
}
```

then i have to case. in the first case i want to add this div to an existing div and in the second i would like to modify an existing div with this one.

I did something like that

```
function addOrModify(value,container){
    // if value = true i add this div to the container
    if(value){
        container.appendChild(createDivStructure());
    }
    //else i want my container to be like the div i created
    else{
        container = createDivStructure();
    }
}
```

But the second case doesn't works, it do nothing and the div remain the same. :x
if i console.log the container and the createDivStructure(); i have the good result.

So here's the question, anyone know how to do that? how can i replace the container with the new div i created?

Thx You :D

Comment: Please expand "doesn't work"

Comment: I'm assuming `container.appendChild(createDivStructure());` works properly, and you need help with the other one?

Comment: It do nothing, the div stay the same. I tryed to remove the first and add the second, but she is added at the end of the container :/

@Cerberus yes sorry i edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function addOrModify(value,container){
    if(value){
        container.appendChild(createDivStructure()); // This seems just fine.
    } else{
        // Insert the new element before the "Target":
        container.parentElement.insertBefore(createDivStructure(), container);
        // Remove the "Target":
        container.parentElement.removeChild(container);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh, was so easy... i must be tired. Thx you so much man :)
'accepted' answer in 6min

Comment: People often forget about `insertBefore` ;-)